# Rewrite/redirect urls to subdomain

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have an add-on on domain that is finally registered and can be accessed without the main domain. The add-on domain have been used like this: (I didn't find similar domain setup to help me out with this)

primary.com/secondary.de/

primary.com/secondary.de/files

primary.com/secondary.de/files/file

I'd like to redirect users to:

secondary.de/

secondary.de/files

secondary.de/files/file

addresses. What expressions should I use in my htacces file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is WP install, put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/secondary.de` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?primary\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(secondary\.de/[^\s]*) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://%1 [NE,R=301,L,NC] 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I put the code under 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' but nothing has changed, the page and address bar is the same whatever url I check.  It's a shared hosting, but mod_rewrite is supported and under the add-on domain a WP site is running.

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled and working. Then tell me what is your full URL that you tried?

Comment: The brackets should remain in the snippet?

Comment: Brackets in `(secondare\.de/.*)` are there for capturing the URL in `$1`

Comment: With or without brackets or placing the htaccess into public_html it's not working. It's a client access site, I cannot give you here login.

Comment: This is very basic mod_rewrite rule. I don't want login, I just wanted your full URL that you used for testing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37527/discussion-between-elbatron-and-anubhava)